# dynamic website development help

Tags: php, web-development, website-design, joomla, drupal

I am wondering is there such thing as a WYSIWYG / graphical editor for PHP based website such as Drupal and Joomla?

I am from the print world, working with code and database just driving me nuts!

Thanks~
Jeno

Answer (score 2):

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) is popular and generally available in content management systems like Drupal and Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like CKEditor.com ?

If not please clarify your question.

Comment: Nop. I am looking for something like Dreamweaver, RapidWeaver, Flux....etc. Software that let you "see" what you doing live instead of working with code and imagine what is going on behind your head.

Comment: I am looking for something user-friendly WYSIWYG graphical editor to develop Drupal PHP based website. I've try Adobe Contribute, and Dreamweaver but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Adobe Contribute](http://www.adobe.com/products/contribute.html)**. From their [FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/contribute/faq.html):

> **What is Adobe® Contribute® CS5, and who is it for?**
>
> **Adobe Contribute CS5 software** enables users to collaboratively
>   author, review, and publish web content — without learning HTML. It is
>   ideal for writers, editors, and content experts who want the freedom
>   to update their own web pages. It is also ideal for web designers and
>   developers who want to maintain the integrity of their design and
>   code.

Comment: Taco HTML Edit maybe?

Comment: I use Contribute. It's great for letting users edit pages, but you need someone who can use Dreamweaver to set up the templates in the first place, and define which parts of the page they can edit. It's not designed to work with Joomla or Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few editors that will help with web development, but none that will get you out of working with the code. [microsoft web matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) is probably the one that will get you the furthest with drupal and joomla. Haven't used it myself so I can't say much about how to work with it, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that well experienced with Drupal, but for Joomla I am quite aware that there is a Joomla DreamWeaver extension, which enables you to use Joomla in collaboration with DreamWeaver. There are so many Joomla editors, kindly check out www.joomla.org